# JS: Validate integer/user input with validation loop and prompt

Tags: javascript, validation, if-statement, while-loop, prompt

I am writing a number guessing game. The guessing game starts by prompting a user for a maximum number (this is not their guess yet--it's the top range for their guess). The prompt should be in a loop with validation, making sure the max number is a (rounded) positive integer. The loop should reprompt the user if the input is 0, <0, or a non-number. I am having trouble getting the validation loop to work.

This is what I have so far, and the prompt works, but the function does not work as I need it to.

```
let suggestion = parseInt(prompt("Help me come up with a range from 1 to a higher number. Type in a number greater than 1."));

function get_suggestion(prompt) {
    let validInput = false;
    let initial_ans, input;
        
    while(!validInput) {
        input = window.prompt(prompt);
        initial_ans = parseInt(input);
    
        if(initial_ans != NaN && initial_ans > 0) {
            validInput = true;
            message.innerHTML = "Guess a number!"
        } 
    }
     return(initial_ans);
}
```

Comment: *but the function does not work as I need it to.* <-- What about it doesn't work the way you need it to?

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Here's how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541). Can you please read it and apply what you learn to improve your question? You can also read [ask] for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the while loop (after assigning prompt/input), replace the if statement in the original code with:

```
// checks to see if user suggestion is a num & a positive int
if (initial_ans != NaN && initial_ans > 0) {
  validInput = true;
  alert("Guess a number between 1 and " + initial_ans + ".");
  message.innerHTML = "Type your number in the field above!";
  reminder.innerHTML = "Guess a number between 1 and " + initial_ans + ".";
```